# Send data to server to update annotations when visible region map is changed or scrolled

Tags: ios

I want to know how update data on annotations consuming web services when the map is scrolled o zoomed as trulia do,  (image below)

[image: Load annotations from webservices when map is scrolled or zoomed]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using this delegate method in order to know when to recalculate pin clusters:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{

}
```

**EDIT**

Check out this pin clustering example!
https://github.com/yinkou/OCMapView

Comment: I'm begginer, how do you recalculate pin cluster? how get I coordinates of the new visible region when the map is scrolled or zoomed?

Comment: oh - sorry!  I thought You knew how to update pins, but didn't knew when. See updated answer!